# Increase CPU to GPU ratio quota on Google Cloud VM

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gpu

When setting up a Google Cloud VM instance, there are fixed ratios of number of GPUs to number of CPUs for the VM. These are described [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/gpus). For example, a machine with 1 NVIDIA T4 GPU can have at most 48 vCPUs. However, a machine with 4 T4 GPUs can have up to 96 CPUs.

I'm wondering if there's any way to exceed these ratios. For example, I would like to run a machine with 64 vCPUs and 1 T4 GPU. Is it possible to do this by requesting a quota increase? Or is this a physical limitation that can't be modified?

For context, I am predicting using a deep learning model that has many input layers. I am pre-processing the inputs (i.e. loading, combining, and normalizing) on the fly just before prediction. This means my job is much more CPU-constrained than GPU-constrained, and I would like to increase the number of CPUs without paying for more GPUs, since I wouldn't be using the additional GPU capacity. Moreover, since I only need to predict once per point, it doesn't seem worth the storage and compute time to pre-process all the data and save pre-processed versions to disk so I can just load these at prediction time (note this is what I did for training).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm wondering if there's any way to exceed these ratios

No, there isn't a way, because these are fixed physical limitations. These ratios are determined by the hardware (and designed in a way so that one part doesn't bottleneck another).

All in all, you **cannot** exceed the fixed ratios you mentioned.